# loop within mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, loops

What I am trying to do is make a first loop, which will organize each entry by "panel_row" and by "panel_page". And within that loop create another loop that will loop thru the rest depending on what "panel_row" grop its in.

```
$query = "SELECT panel_row FROM panels WHERE panel_page = '{$onpage}'ORDER BY panel_row";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);

//$panel_row = $row["panel_row"];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo '<div class="row">';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM panels WHERE panel_page = '{$onpage}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '
            <div '.$row["panel_size"].'">
            <div class="">
            <div class="">
            <h3 class=""><b>'.$row["panel_title"].'</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="">
            '.$row["panel_content"].'
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            ';
        }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

so the end result will display something like this, within the same panel_page..

```
<div class="row">//Panel_row #1

//The rest of the information depending on what row we are in..
        <div '.$row["panel_size"].'">
            <div class="">
            <div class="">
            <h3 class=""><b>'.$row["panel_title"].'</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="">
            '.$row["panel_content"].'
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div '.$row["panel_size"].'">
            <div class="">
            <div class="">
            <h3 class=""><b>'.$row["panel_title"].'</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="">
            '.$row["panel_content"].'
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

</div>

<div class="row">//Panel_row #2

        <div '.$row["panel_size"].'">
            <div class="">
            <div class="">
            <h3 class=""><b>'.$row["panel_title"].'</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="">
            '.$row["panel_content"].'
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div '.$row["panel_size"].'">
            <div class="">
            <div class="">
            <h3 class=""><b>'.$row["panel_title"].'</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="">
            '.$row["panel_content"].'
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

</div>

TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `panels` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `panel_page` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `panel_row` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `panel_size` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `panel_order` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `panel_title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `panel_content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: ok. And what is your question?

Comment: zhank you acel, you were faster :D

Comment: Well the first loop is not working, it will only display one <div class="row"> instead of each one. I need a working mysqli query to make the first loop work.